# Why does Set-Acl on the drive root try to set ownership of the "object"?

Tags: powershell, acl

I would like to change the ACL of the `C:` drive. What im trying to do is remove the permission that a user can create a folder directly on the drive. I tested the script on another folder while writing it. It worked without a problem. After completion i tried the script in our test envoirnment on the actual drive. I get an error that i cant figure out. If i remove the permission manualy it works without a problem. Anyone got an idea?

```
$path = "C:\"

$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"CreateDirectories"

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Authenticated Users") 
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL $path 
$objACL.RemoveAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL $path $objACL
```

The error is:

```
Set-Acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.
At C:\Users\mhodler\Desktop\Remove Permission.ps1:57 char:8
+ Set-ACL <<<<  $path $objACL
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\:String) [Set-Acl], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Comment: Found the answer. Sorry for posting it here. I dont have the permission to post an answer to my own question in the next 4hrs.

Replace

    $objACL = Get-ACL $path
With

    $objACL = (get-item $path).getaccesscontrol("Access")

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I found the answer. Microsoft says

> Unfortunately `Get-Acl` is missing some features. It always reads the full security descriptor even if you just want to modify the DACL. That’s why `Set-ACL` also wants to write the owner even if you have not changed it. Using the `GetAccessControl` method allows you to specify what part of the security descriptor you want to read.

Replace the `Get-Acl` call with

```
$acl = (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('Access')
```

Comment: Can you cite the Microsoft source please?

Comment: The earliest reference to this I could find was a Dec 14, 2010 blog that quoted Microsoft without citing the source: https://web.archive.org/web/20120107061856/http://www.bilalaslam.com/2010/12/14/powershell-workaround-for-the-security-identifier-is-not-allowed-to-be-the-owner-of-this-object-with-set-acl/

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz the response from MS was from a Microsoft employee "Babak Ramak" in the old TechNet Powershell Forum - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/870fab41-439b-4f3a-ace4-cbfe4e41f789/powershell-setacl-use-without-changing-owner?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 8):

You need the `SeRestorePrivilege` to set the owner.  I used Lee Holmes' script from the URL below to elevate my process with this additional priv and was able to set the owner to someone other than myself.

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/09/24/adjusting-token-privileges-in-powershell/

I tried the `(get-item $path).getaccesscontrol("access")` method but still got the same error since my process didn't have the `SeRestorePrivilege`.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Found via Google, and helped me solve a completely different problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was the point for me. I also discovered that a possible workaround to set the owner is to use the "local UNC" version of the path, e.g. if you want to set the owner for C:\test.txt you need to call SetAccessControl method on the item (get-item "\\localhost\C$\test.txt")

Comment: Although this works, I prefer the selected solution about rather using (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('Access') to get the ACL object

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me:

```
$ApplicationPoolIdentity = "everyone"

function SetACL()
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]        $Path 
    )

    $Acl = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl('Access')
    Write-Host "Path:" $Path "ID:" $ApplicationPoolIdentity
    $Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($ApplicationPoolIdentity,"Write","Allow")
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    Write-Host $Acl
    $Acl | Set-Acl $Path
}

SetACL "C:\Test\"
```

Answer (score 0):

People may find this easier:

```
icacls c:\ /remove "authenticated users"
```

Answer (score -1):

$Acl = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl('Access')

Worked for me.
I run my PS Script from CMD and in this PS Script i run another PS Script everything works fine as long as i do it with my own User. When i use different User i get the same Error:
Set-Acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.

Just changed Get-ACL to that Line above and it worked fine.
Thanks again.

Comment: No need to create an answer to thank anybody's else answer